# Verify the following integral is an Ito stochastic integral and a martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

> Let $S(t)$ be the standard stock price expression $S(0)$ $\exp \left[\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2}\right) t+\sigma B(t)\right]$. Verify that $\int_{t=0}^{1} \sigma S(t) d B(t)$ is an Ito stochastic integral.

I got the SDE of $S_t$, $$dS_t=\mu S_t\:dt+\sigma S_t\: dB_t$$
Now, we want to get the stochastic integral, $$\int_{t=0}^{1} \sigma S(t) d B(t)$$
We may want to reverse engineer $f(t,x)$ using Ito's formula as follows. Ito's formula gives:

$$ \,d f(t,S_t) = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,S_t) + \mu S_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,S_t) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t,S_t)\right)\,d t + \sigma S_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,S_t)\,d B_t$$  or,
$$ \int_0^T\sigma S_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,S_t)\,d B_t = f(t,S_t) - f(0,S_0) - \int_0^T\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,S_t) + \mu S_t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,S_t) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t,S_t)\right)\,d t.$$
So we will be done if we can find $f$ such that $$ \sigma x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x) = \sigma x$$ which will lead us to the integral $$ f(t,x) - f(t,0) = \int_0^xdy=x-x_0 $$
But, now I feel lost. From here, how can I conclude something? Like, I need to show that the $M_t\:\left( \int_{t=0}^{1} \sigma S(t) d B(t) \right)$ is driftless. But from here, how can I?

Comment: It is well-known that $M_t=\int_0^tS_sdB_s$ is a Ito integral and a martingale. In particular it is driftless. Given the special form of $S_t$ you are probably overthinking it.

Comment: Actually, my book didn't explicitly mention $M_t=\int_0^tS_tdB_s$ is an Ito integral and a martingale. If I need to show that, then what will be the correct way to solve? And thanks for your response @KurtG.

Comment: Which book is that ?  I recommend to study the proof that $M_t$ is a (local) martingale. This is one of the most basic things to learn. Take the book by Karatzss and Shreve for example.

Comment: We have taught the first 5 chapters of **"brownian motion calculus by wiersema"**. Can you cite the proof? Or let me know the section number from Shreve. I have exam tomorrow and still hanging on these question  @KurtG.

Comment: Wiersema mentions on page 121 that such integrals are martingales. As far as I can tell this is part of chapter **5** . If you want to prove it yourself take a simple deterministic integrand and use the martingale property of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

First we the  $\int_{t=0}^{1} \sigma S(t) d B(t)$ is well defined because

$$E[S(t)^{2}]=e^{2\mu t-\sigma^{2}t+2\sigma^{2}t}<\infty.$$

Next we show martingale. Because $S(t)$ is adapted we have

$$E\left[\int_{t=0}^{T} \sigma S(t) d B(t)\mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right]$$

$$ =E\left[\int_{s}^{T}\sigma S(t) d B(t)\mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right]+\int_{0}^{s}\sigma S(t) d B(t).$$

So it suffices to show that the first integral is zero. We add and subtract $B_{s}$

$$ e^{B(s)}E\left[\int_{s}^{T}\sigma \exp \left[\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2}\right) t+\sigma B(t)-B(s)\right] d B(t)\mid \mathcal{F}_{s}\right].$$

Therefore, by independent increments we get

$$ =e^{B(s)}E\left[\int_{0}^{T}\sigma \exp \left[\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2}\right) t+\sigma B(t)-B(0)\right] d B(t)\right].$$

This is equal to zero because by generally for a predictable process $f(s,\omega)$ we have

$$E\int f(s)dB_{s}]=E\lim \sum f(t_{i})(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_{i}})$$

$$=\lim \sum E[f(t_{i})]E[(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_{i}})]$$

$$=\lim \sum E[f(t_{i})]0=0.$$